# Postgres JSON querying - match all pairs, ignore order

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a Postgres table that contains a `jsonb` column, the data in which is arbitrarily deep.

```
id | jsonb_data
---|----------------------
1  | '{"a":1}'
2  | '{"a":1,"b":2}'
3  | '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":{"d":4}}'
```

Given a JSON object in my `WHERE` clause, I want to find the rows that contain objects that contain the same data and no more, but *in any order.* Including, preferably, nested objects.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE json_match_ignore_order(jsonb_data, '{"b":2,"a":1}');

id | jsonb_data
---|-----------
2  | '{"a":1,"b":2}'
```

This would essentially work identically to the following Ruby code, but I'd really like to do it in the database if possible.

```
table.select { |row| row.jsonb_data_as_a_hash == {b: 2, a: 1} }
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `jsonb` type you can use equal sign even for values with nested objects.

Thus the following will also work:

```
create table jsonb_table(
  id serial primary key,
  jsonb_data jsonb
);

insert into jsonb_table(jsonb_data)
values
  ('{"a":1}'),
  ('{"a":{"c":5},"b":2}'),
  ('{"a":{"c":5},"b":2,"c":{"d":4}}');

select * from jsonb_table
where jsonb_data = '{"b":2,"a":{"c":5}}'::jsonb;
```

You will get rows with objects containing same keys with same values recursively (in this case only the second row).

Comment: Excellent! I had no idea it would be so simple :D